# iPhone Dev - "More" TabBarItem - how to change the title?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using TabBarController and I have more than 10 View Controllers in it (that's why I can see "More" tab, where I can access the rest of the views). My question is:

Is there any way to change the title of the "More" tab bar? (I know how to change the title of the view:

tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"SuperMore";

but I would like to change the text on the bar itself. Is it possible, anyway? ;-)

Big thanks in adv.
Charles

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change this using the API.  If you really want to change it, just create your own icon with your own text for the 5th tab bar item.  You will then implement your own Table View Controller for the tab which will duplicate the default "More" tab. It will be difficult to re-implement if you wish to include reordering/customization of the tabs, but if you are fine with locking them in, it should not be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks for reply! It's a shame one cannot change this simple property... :-/

Comment: yes, the only thing that seems to be editable is the text of the title of the more button, but it does not influence anything else (tab bar items etc)